# Python compare dictionary to dictionary of conditions

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an iterator (millions of rows) that gives me a dictionary that need to be compared against a dictionary of conditions to find matches.

Here is my code:

```
conditions={"port":"0-20", "ip":"1.2.3.4", "protocol":"1,7",
            "timestamp":">143990000", "server":"mario"}

for rec in imiterator(): # Very large number of rows
    # rec examples {"ip":"1.7.1.1", "timestamp":1434000,
    #              "port":129,"server":("mario","bruno"), 
    #              "protocol":"1","port":19"}

    if check_conditions(rec, conditions):
       print(json.dumps(rec))
```

Note the columns in `rec` can be `int`, `long`, `string`, `tuple`.

I need to find a real high performance way to do the matches.  Any ideas?

I thought about using `map` and converting the conditions to lambda functions that should match and doing an AND operation of all the conditions.  Would this be faster?

Comment: The conditions are all logical and not just 1:1 - so the port range in example 0-20 means the port can be in the range of 0 through 20. The protocol 1,7 means the protocol can be either 1 or 7

Comment: You'll have to use or design a DSL to express those conditions. There's no simple answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done, converted my conditions to an dictionary of lambda functions and have used the first record object to figure out what type of function I want it to be - either a basic string match, numeric match or a range (greater than and lesser than cane also ranges with 0-100 or -100 is less than 100 and 100- is greater than 100)

```
def check_condition(rec,val):
    matched=True # by default return true if there is no questions asked
    for cond in val:
        cmatch=val[cond](rec.__getattribute__(cond))
        if not cmatch: # current match is false just return False for this record
            return False
        matched=matched and cmatch
    return matched



conditions={"port":"0-20","ip":"1.2.3.4","protocol":"1,7","timestamp":"143990000-","server":"!mario"}
def check_condition(rec,val):
    matched=True # by default return true if there is no questions asked
    for cond in val:
        cmatch=val[cond](rec.__getattribute__(cond))
        if not cmatch: # current match is false just return False for this record
            return False
        matched=matched and cmatch
    return matched
def number_logic_to_lambda(invar,switcharoo):
        """
    This subroutine does check the request to be either a range query or a comma delimited list or a single number
    """
        z=invar.split('-') # range queries 
        if len(z) == 1:
            y=map(int,invar.split(',')) # multiple conditions
            if len(y) == 1: # a single match
                return lambda x: (x == int(y[0]))^switcharoo
            else: # This is a comma delimited convert to list and send match condition back
                return lambda x: (x in y)^switcharoo
        elif len(z) == 2: # This is a query with "-" 
            if z[1] == '': # This is a greater than query
                return lambda x: (int(z[0]) <= x)^switcharoo
            elif x[0] == '': # This is a less than query
                return lambda x: (int(z[0]) >= x)^switcharoo
            else: # This is range query
                return lambda x: (int(z[0]) <= x <= int(z[1]))^switcharoo
    iter=imiterator()
 first_rec=next(iter)
 nvars={} # This is conditions changed into functions
 for svar in conditions:
    qvar=conditions[svar]
    switcharoo=False
    if qvar.startswith("!"): # Start with a bang it is a negative condition
       qvar=qvar.replace("!","")
       switcharoo=True   
       mapf=lambda x: x == qvar # default mapping function full string match
       if isinstance(cattr,int): #the next three treat them as numeric
           mapf=number_logic_to_lambda(qvar,switcharoo)
       elif isinstance(cattr,float): # float is also treated like a number
           mapf=number_logic_to_lambda(float(qvar),switcharoo)
       elif isinstance(cattr,long):  # long is also treated numeric
           mapf=number_logic_to_lambda(qvar,switcharoo)
       elif isinstance(cattr,tuple): # Tuples can use set intersection
           print set(qvar.split(","))
           mapf=lambda x: (set(qvar.split(",")).issubset(set(x))) ^ switcharoo
       nvars[svar]=mapf # update the dictionary of mapped functions

 rec=next(iter,None)
 while rec: # very large number of rows
     #rec examples {"ip":"1.7.1.1","timestamp":1434000,"port":129,"server":("mario","bruno"), "protocol":"1","port":19"}
      if check_conditions(rec,nvars):
          print json.dumps(rec)
      rec=next(iter,None)
```

Answer (score -1):

If the goal is to check 1:1 correspondence, why don't you convert all the entries of rec into string and just do a,

```
return conditions == rec
```

If the goal is to process and understand the data that is in a range then it could have different processing standard, but for such trivial task, using map would only increase the overhead.

Comment: It looks like OP wants to be able to use some logic, e.g. `"timestamp":">143990000"`

Comment: Sorry for not explaining.  The conditions are all logical and not just 1:1 - so the port range in example 0-20 means the port can be in the range of 0 through 20. The protocol 1,7 means the protocol can be either 1 or 7

Comment: The IP in this case treated as a string, so just 1:1 comparison is good.  It is not string partial match.  If we get a good methodology then I could think of subnets, partial strings etc.  later. But the current search requirements are not that.